# Assigning a function pointer with variable arguments using parameter pack

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

I would like to store as a member variable a pointer to a function that may take a variable number of arguments of different types.

The basic construct I've been trying to use is along these lines

```
template <typename... Args>
using ArgsFuncPointer = void(*)(Args...);

template<typename... Args> void varArgsFunc(Args&&... args) {  }

{
    ArgsFuncPointer<int, float> funcPointer = varArgsFunc;   
    funcPointer(1, 2.0);
}
```

The problem is that `varArgsFunc` cannot be converted to `ArgsFuncPointer<int, float>`

See [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b73aab6db68c8174) for a (non-)working example.

Ultimately I would like to be able to do something like:

```
template <typename... Args> class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(Args&&... args)
    {
        func(args);
    }

    VarArgsFuncPointer func;
}
```

**UPDATE**

It turns out the reason this wouldn't compile is due to the subtle difference in signature between `ArgsFuncPointer` and `varArgsFunc`. With `ArgsFuncPointer` the parameter pack is passed by rvalue reference, whereas with `varArgsFunc` the parameter pack is passed by value.

This works:

```
template <typename... Args>
using ArgsFuncPointer = void(*)(Args&&...);

template<typename... Args> void varArgsFunc(Args&&... args) {  }

{
    ArgsFuncPointer<int, float> funcPointer = varArgsFunc;   
    funcPointer(1, 2.0);
}
```

Working example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e585f1ca7aeacb0)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `varArgsFunc` is a *template* not a specific function, but `ArgsFuncPointer<int, float>` is a pointer to a specific function.

Untested, but you should be able to specify the actual function instance by specifying its template arguments:

```
ArgsFuncPointer<int, float> funcPointer = varArgsFunc<int, float>;
//                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                Must specify template arguments
```

---

On another note, I recommend that you use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead of pointers to *non-member* functions. That will allow you to use [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) or [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) or just about any callable object.

Using `std::function` would be very similar to what you have now:

```
template <typename... Args>
using ArgsFuncPointer = std::function<void(Args...)>;
```

Then using a lambda you could do something like

```
ArgsFuncPointer<int, float> funcPointer = [](int i, float f)
{
    varArgsFunc(i, f);  // Call the real function
};
```

Comment: Actually that's not right, see my update to the question. The issue was a difference in signature between the function pointer and the function pointer type being assigned to. `std::function` is a potential alternative, can you provide an example equivalent to the above using `std::function` ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you up to something like

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
using ArgsFuncPointer = void(*)(Args...);

template <typename... Args> class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(Args&&... args)
    {
        func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    ArgsFuncPointer<Args...> func;
};
```

Packs need to be expanded when used in expressions.

Comment: Thanks. I've resolved my underlying issue (see update) but I've also realised that `template <typename... Args> class` isn't going to be workable for what I need since the parameter pack propagates to any parent classes and things start to get complicated very quickly. I think I need a completely different solution